# Set specific App to ignore optimization by code in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In the new `Android M` build, the Battery Optimization feature will stop the app on certain condition to save battery, but for the `VOIP`apps that need to stay alive all the time, this feature cause troubles for the developer.

Currently there is one way to bypass the optimization, which is set the app to ignore optimizations,but too many steps need to be done.

My question is, is there a way to jump to ignore optimization page of specific App, and how can I know whether my app is excluded from optimization?

Comment: Same for my App.. Any update on this ?

Comment: you don't need to stay alive all the time, you can simply send a high priority GCM when you need to do stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315057/android-m-how-to-send-a-high-priority-gcm

Answer (score 8):

**WARNING: It seems Google doesn't allow apps on the Play Store to do this. See the comments below.**

Based on the AndroidManifest.xml extracted from Settings.apk in the MPA44I build, it would seem you might be able to do what you want by something like the intent below.

From XML:

```
<intent
    android:action="android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"
    android:targetPackage="com.android.settings"
    android:data="package:PUT_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE" />
```

From code:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:PUT_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE"));
    startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that I have not had time to verify this in practice myself but the approach is the same as I use in one of my apps to launch app-specific settings menus. Still, I hope it helps.

Comment: Be careful with this - my app just got suspended from Google Play without prior notice for requesting `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`, even though exempting the app from battery optimizations is crucial to my app's function, and I can't use GCM for technical reasons.

Comment: @EladNava I'm sorry to hear that. I hope you were able to get it solved. I'll  include a warning in my answer above.

Comment: @EladNava Truecaller app pops up this "Ignore Battery Optimizations?" prompt and they are on Google play. (WHY?)

Comment: Maybe they received explicit permission from Google. I don't know, I just wanted to warn everyone as my app got suspended for requesting this, even though the permission was critical to its function.

Comment: There are use cases where Google allows it or denies it. Check this: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases

Comment: And you also need, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />` permission. It is not a `dangerous` permission so you don't need to ask the user for permission. It is automatically provided to you

Comment: Google will suspend applications based on not having the "appearance" of necessity. They recently suspended my chat app for the permission, but the documentation provided in the suspension validated having it. The "person" sending the email (if a person at all) is not a developer. You can file an appeal and explain their policies or how their own services work to them in order to get the suspension revoked. It is sad they take such aggressive steps with such a blind automated process. Even Apple takes the time to open a dialogue for such issues.

Comment: @LoungeKatt who / which e-mail address did you contact at Google to get them to let you add this permission to your app and upload to Google Play? I am in a similar situation (Doze stops GPS in my app working) and I can't find out how to get Google to let me use this permission! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds I didn't contact them. They sent one of their automated messages to suspend my application and I appealed it. I cited their own documentation and the lack of competence by their review staff, which was only further evident by the month it took to process the appeal. Given, it came long after I had taken the backlash for not using the permission to avoid losing all of my customers to the suspension.

Comment: Check Support for Other Use Cases here https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases

Comment: This does not work. REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS is a permission, not a field of Settings. And you need this permission in the Manifest to be able to start the request.

Comment: @neoexpert: Not sure what you're talking about? It is both a permission and a field in Settings. https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/lineage-16.0/AndroidManifest.xml#L1139

Answer (score 4):

Google Allow this based on few conditions 
Check Section "Support For Other Use Cases"

[here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases)

Also check [White List Conditions](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to effectively opt out of optimizations, as this does not affect doze mode - even if your app is on the whitelist.

See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31721398/4301846

and here:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2225