# How to send a high-priority GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using a Nexus 5 with Android M Preview.

My problem that I'm trying to solve is:

> Network access is disabled, unless your app receives a high priority
>   Google Cloud Messaging tickle.

What I'm doing is:

I put the phone into Doze mode and then I send a push notification with the priority with value 10 and I'm expecting to have internet access for a brief moments, but this is not working.

Should I use other type of notifications? There are any documentation already available?

Thanks.

Android M changes:
https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html

What I found about GCM priority messages:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting priority to 10 is the correct thing to do, but it does not work with the version of Android M released at I/O. It has been fixed, and priority 10 messages will work as expected with the public release.

Comment: @morepork: So it won't work in any Preview Release or do i miss the point? Do you have a link?

Comment: Please see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: if we don't set priority, what will be the default priority High or normal?

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

In fact, it's related with Google Play Services version not Android version. Use "high" for priority.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this into your File (.php, .jsf, etc):

```
$fields = array(
                    'registration_ids' => $android,
                    **'priority' => 'high',**
                    'data' => array( 'message' => $message,
                                     'title' => $title,                                 
                                     'created_at' => $created_at,                                
                                     'is_background' => $is_background,
                                     'pantallaMostrarPushAndroid' => "pushNotificationNormal")
                ); 

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

                // Execute post
                $resultAndroid = curl_exec($ch);
```