# How do I properly fire ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, optimization, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

As stated in the documentation:

> "An app holding the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission can trigger a system dialog to let the user add the app to the whitelist directly, without going to settings. The app fires a ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS Intent to trigger the dialog."

Can someone tell me the proper way to fire this intent?

Comment: One alternative is doit by adb or make your command line tool inside your app to call something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685874/3174791) , that work perfectly to me

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Java

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
else {
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```

### Kotlin

```kotlin
val intent = Intent()
val pm : PowerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.packageName)) {
    intent.action = Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS
} else {
    intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
    intent.data = Uri.parse("package:${context.packageName}")
}
context.startActivity(intent)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316491/network-access-in-doze-mode/32424117#32424117) for more information.

Comment: Be careful with this - my app just got suspended from Google Play without prior notice for requesting `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`, even though exempting the app from battery optimizations is crucial to my app's function, and I can't use GCM for technical reasons.

Comment: @EladNava Did you write to Google about the issue?

Comment: @milosmns I did, and waiting for their reply. My app is currently suspended and inaccessible as I wait for their verdict. I seem to be the first person to have posted about getting suspended for requesting `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`, for **perfectly legitimate** reasons (crucial to app + GCM technical difficulties). These are the 2 conditions listed in their [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases) for requesting the permission. Will update when they reach their decision.

Comment: @EladNava Yeah, bummer. Hopefully people will see these comments before using the same approach.

Comment: @milosmns They decided that the only way my app will be reinstated is if I remove the `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission, even though I explained that according to the docs I had every right to request it. I decided to remove it so that I won't risk permanent deletion of the app. It seems that Google is extremely trigger-happy and emotionless about suspending and permanently banning apps on Google Play.

Comment: late reply, but @Elad: Is your app still removed? What did Google give as justification for suspending your app? I can´t understand Googles behaviour, if an app really needs this, why they nevertheless suspend the app? :(

Comment: @Opiatefuchs It has been reinstated, after I had sent Google Play Developer Support several e-mails and attempted to appeal the suspension. I also know someone who works at Google whom I asked to help me with this.

Comment: Thanks for reply.....I really don´t get it....I don´t know why Google suddenly acts apple-like :( . If they clear state out which apps are acceptable for beeing on the whitelist and which not, where is the problem if it matches the case?

Comment: And really, the new Doze mode and App standby is not as user friendly as they think. I read about many complaints from users. A simple thing would be, to give an option in the device settings for the users to enable/disable doze mode and app standby. If they would do it, everybody will be happy.

Comment: @EladNava so how do we avoid suspension? My app doesn't have internet access but is similar to skype (using external hardware) i.e. has to display incoming calls and is time critical

Comment: @behelit I'd attempt to get Google's written approval of your use-case before asking for this permission in your app. Not sure if they have such a process but try to get in touch with them anyway to avoid unexpected suspension.

Comment: Elad, could you please tell me how to contact them as directly as possible for such a topic? My alarm clock needs two alarms which might be as near as 10-15 minutes apart, and the second one is not fired then. So it seems I need approval on their part.

Comment: @Buddy i am not able to open any popup or screen using above code.i paste code in onStart, onResume and finally in onCreate but i cant get any things. i just show blink like something open and close same time. i cant understand the situation my target api is 23.

Comment: The Intent is not fired for me?

Comment: This will only trigger if you have     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Andrew Thanks it helped.

Comment: @powder366 have you published your app with this permission? Did you read the warning in the above comments? (you might get kicked out of Google Play)

Comment: No I didnt. I guided the user to settings to let them change on their own.

Comment: @EladNava I know that this is an old thread, but in the end how did you do? Removed the permission? Basically not having the permission but letting the user know how to do the Whitelisting manually is an ok case for Google?

Comment: @Alin I ended up removing the permission. I manually guide users that complain about the app not working to whitelist the app from battery optimizations.

Comment: If already app is ignoringBatteryOptimization, what "intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);" is for? Why you need to open setting page?

Comment: @EladNava Thanks for raising this. When you app got banned, did you have the permission in the manifest or only in the code?

Comment: @EladNava thanks! As I understand, if *not* declaring this in the manifest, directing users directly to the opt out page (by calling startActivity() with this action and app id as data) is safe.

Comment: @auval Yes, that is correct. Google is only against apps allowing users to whitelist battery optimizations from *within the app* via the in-app dialog. Taking the user to the battery optimizations page is fine.

Comment: The `if` statement in this code seems unnecessary and even counterproductive... I mean, this answer isn't about opening the battery optimization settings, it's about disabling Doze mode. So why does the `if` default to that?

Comment: Android Studio now will tell you that there are acceptable cases where you can use this permission: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases

Comment: I noticed that famous app such as Deezer or Spotify are never killed when playing music in background and they don't request ignoring battery optimization. Does anyone know how they achieve that ?

Comment: Is it possible to have any callback for the user selection?

Comment: @AmirUval do you have any code sample where you have guided the user to disable it ?

Comment: @SiddarthG three years ago I had ;-)

Comment: isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations is allways false, any Idea why ?

Comment: i can redirect user to setting screen, guide him to select no restrictions from battery saver, is it the same as redirecting user to battery optimization screen?

Comment: This code makes no sense. It shows two alternative ways of whitelisting the app: directly using a system dialog (requires permission and will probably get the app banned in Google Play) and opening the Settings UI to show the list of all whitelisted/optimized apps. Why would you do one or the other depending on the result of `pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations`?

Answer (score 20):

To avoid suspension from Google Play Store, Its Better to Take User to Battery Optimization Settings, for Manually Adding Application to White-list

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Also It doesn't need to have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

permission in the manifest file

Comment: Without the permission  startActivity() doesnt do anything

Comment: I agree with @KgaboL that if the android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS is missing from the manifest then starting the activity with the action Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS doesn't do anything.  I however do want to take the user to the page for *them* to manually turn it on.

Comment: Meanwhile it seems funny you can take the user to a page via ActionIgnoreBatteryOptimizationSettings to see you are not optimised.  I just want to be taken to the page where I'm optimised so I can disable it 

Comment: It works perfectly without permissions. The permission is only needed for `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`. If it doesn't work check that you are not adding the `setData` line to the intent. The intent should only have an action, as shown in this answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        myIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
    }
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not sufficient, please provide a little explanation on your code

Comment: This makes no sense. You call startActivity with an empty intent if SDK < M.

Comment: Also as @Jamile mentions above, you need the permission in the manifest for this to work, which I'm seeing a lot of warnings saying your app can be yanked from Google Play... Seems harsh if it results in a dialog being displayed letter the user make a choice.