# Android app not visible on power save mode samsung s8

Tags: android, android-permissions, power-saving

When I switch on power save mode on my samsung s8, My app is not visible to use which we are developing now,When we press Plus + button facebook and whatsup and etc are there. What I am missing what kind of permission i need to give or what i have to do. and we have declared permission in manifest. Thanks in advance.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Comment: Are you using any background services in your app ? Music app doesn't work in UPSM because some background services has been turn off. In the same way you also may have some. check it

Comment: this may give some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083670/how-do-i-make-my-android-app-appear-in-ultra-power-saving-mode

Comment: Yes I have STICKY service and it will be always connected to my server, its calling based app not music, i went through above given link before this post no help with that.

Comment: Then Check this, here are Acceptable Use Cases for Whitelisting https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases.  But i am not aware much about this topic. will look into it if got some time