# How to opt-out an app from Doze mode?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

How to opt-out my app from android M DOZE mode ?
Is there a standard way to include and exclude apps from DOZE and auto standby selectively at run time ?

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35914341/2826147).

Answer (score 5):

> How to opt-out my app from android M DOZE mode ?

You can't by any known mechanism.

> Is there a standard way to include and exclude apps from DOZE and auto standby selectively at run time ?

In theory, the user can toggle an "Ignore optimizations" option in Settings, to put the app on a whitelist of apps that should not go into app standby mode. This will not affect doze mode.

Quoting [somebody who I believe is Dianne Hackborn](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2225#c11):

> While the device is dozing, syncs and jobs are turned off globally, putting an app on the whitelist does not change the behavior for them.  This is the intended behavior, as is the lack of free use of the alarm manager.  (One of the key aspects of all of these is that they are ways to cause the device to wake up, and anything that causes it to wake up will have a significant impact on battery life in the durations we want to last while dozing, so it is simply not allowed.)
>
> While dozing, the AndAllowWhileIdle APIs allow you to wake up the device at most once every 15 minutes; when not dozing this is raise to once every minute.  When the device is in idle maintenance mode, all of the doze restrictions are removed (so AllowWhileIdle can happen once a minute).

Note that "idle maintenance mode" is presently undocumented. My guess is that this refers to a device that is idle but is charging.

Comment: "idle maintenance mode" seems to be the little time window opening once in a while in idle mode, allowing applications to do processing. Gotten from here: https://newcircle.com/s/post/1739/2015/06/12/diving-into-android-m-doze