# Creating app with no power save optimalizations

Tags: android

I'm working currently on Android app that requires constant gps updates and network access. Location should be acquired every minute, request should be send to server every three minutes, even when the phone is in sleep mode and app is in background. The app will run constantly for hours, maybe even days.

The problem is, all the power save features are making my app work with delays. What can i do to ensure that app is running without any optimalizations?

- users know that this app is energy consuming, and it's crucial for them to be sure that it is working without delays
- i'm targeting Android 4.1 and later

Comment: did u check whitelist the app from doze mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627342/how-to-whitelist-app-in-doze-mode-android-6-0 ?

Comment: yes, but it is only for Marshmallow