# What is system API for stoping Doze for an App on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, power-saving

I am looking for android **system API** implementation for avoiding Doze for particular application. Rather requesting user to confirm adding in whitelisted app for doze.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without user interaction. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32627788/368379

Comment: Compare the package name and you could avoid it

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for more clean approach.I am sure it is not public must hidden somewhere in android source :) .