# Disabling battery optimization

Tags: android, android-intent, android-background, huawei-mobile-services

Huawei and Honor devices have a mode called "power intensive app" that notifies the user of abnormally consuming apps.

```
Settings > Battery > "gear icon" > "Close excessively power-intensive apps" > On/Off
```

Is there a way to disable it programmatically in Huawei and Honor devices?
If not, is there someone who knows an intent that call the battery menu so i can disable it manually?

I have already try

```
Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY
Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to WhiteList app in Doze mode Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627342/how-to-whitelist-app-in-doze-mode-android-6-0)

Comment: Maybe a good time to check WHY your app is power-intensive. Is there something you can do about it?

Comment: @AbdulRauf you post is for "white listed app". This is another case

Comment: @Henry I have a service that run in background. I can't delete it

Comment: disable battery optimizations = whitelist application for doze mode. Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627788/2073920 which is using `ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` intent

Comment: @AbdulRauf "power intensive app" is a huawei's feature and it is different from whitelist application