# Getting "BLOCKED" network state when Android's data saver is off

Tags: java, android, android-connectivitymanager, networkinfo

I am developing an app to be used on a specific tablet running Android 7.0. I'm using a `Service` to send periodic `DatagramPacket`s. **I can only use mobile networks**. I check the connectivity status using `ConnectivityManager`, `NetworkInfo` and `DetailedState`. I get the network state with this code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
DetailedState networkState = activeNetwork.getDetailedState();
```

- If the tablet is plugged in and the screen is on or off, I get [CONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState#CONNECTED) state.
- If the tabled is unplugged and the screen is on, I get CONNECTED state.
- If the tabled is unplugged and **the screen is off**, I get [BLOCKED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState#BLOCKED) state.

In my tablet the Data Saver is off. Just in case, I have run tests to verify there are no restrictions when the screen turns off, `cm.getRestrictBackgroundStatus()` always returns 1, which is [RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED), even when the network is blocked.

So, why is the network blocked? Do my app need special permissions? Do my tablet need special configuration?

Comment: The phone has gone into the idle state and internet connectivity is not allowed in that state. Its a way to conserve battery power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to give a complete solution I will answer my question.

> **why is the network blocked?**

As the documentation provided by Stanislav Kireev pointed, this [BLOCKED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState#BLOCKED) network state happens because the device is in Doze. This device state does not allow internet access starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23).

But the documentation also says that "the system provides a configurable whitelist of apps that are partially exempt from Doze and App Standby optimizations". For more detailed explanation you can read [Support for other use cases](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases) section. You can add your app to the whitelist from code or configuring the system.

> **Do my app need special permissions?**

If you need to add your app to the whitelist from code, you need to add a permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

And add this code to your activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I got this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42651399/4600693).

> **Do my tablet need special configuration?**

If you want, you can add your app from **Settings > Battery > 3 dots > Battery optimisation**. Choose **All apps** in the pick list, select your app and choose **Don’t optimise** option.

I got this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542354/4600693) (it has more detailed explanation).

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behaviour. When your screen is locked, it use doze mode. And Doze mode turn off internet communication and all background services. You need wakeup your device and after you can make all actions with internet. [Documentations](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: Reading the documentation you linked, I can see that the app can be whitelisted to avoid battery optimization (here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases). If you add this to your answer I will accept it.