# Disable Battery Optimization through REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: android, optimization, google-play, battery

We have an app on Play Store, which is used by businesses for field service. This app provides location updates of the users to our servers on a regular interval. The location data is used to calculate the amount of time spent by a user in a specific predefined geofence area, which the users create themselves.

To get a better tracking experience, we have asked our users to disable battery optimization through a popup which tells them the steps as follow -

- Click DISABLE in our custom popup (where we mention that disabling battery optimization will give them more consistent location tracking experience)
- Select 'All Apps' from Battery Optimization Android Settings page
- Search and select our app name
- Select 'Don't Optimize'.

The average age group of our users is > 45 years and they are not tech-savvy. We received feedback from them asking us for a simplified way to disable battery optimization instead of following all the above complicated steps.

We can disable battery optimization in one click using REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS in manifest permission. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150246)

But it seems our app might get removed from Play Store if we do so without approval from Google. We tried reaching out to Google through the Play Developer Console support tickets, but didn't receive any response for more than a month.

Location tracking and continuous flow of coordinates is one of the important features of our app. We also show a persistent notification to user which tell them that there location is being tracked.

Can someone provide any guidance on how to get that approval for our use case?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I not sure whether You use `requestLocationUpdates()` in Service like Bound-service and use `startForeground()` when your service is in `onUnbind()`.

And you have to `stopForeground()` when service is `onBind()` or `onRebind()`